# c# upload file to stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, stream, web

I want the user to upload a file and save it to a stream.

Here is the code so far:

```
 private void Submit_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


               fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);

        }
```

Comment: What is your problem then? Where are you stuck? Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I want to read it into a stream.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do  like this

```
  string filePath = uploadFile(fileUploadControl.FileContent);

private string uploadFile(Stream serverFileStream)
{
    string filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadTempDir"] + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm") + "_" + 
    Customer.GetCustomerName(CustomerId).Replace(" ", "_") + ".txt";

   try
   {
    int length = 256;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];

    // write the required bytes
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        do
        {
            bytesRead = serverFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        while (bytesRead == length);
    }

    serverFileStream.Dispose();
    return filename;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    lblErrorMessage.Text += "An unexpeded error occured uploading the file. " + ex.Message;
    return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

i hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 3):

The object that `FileUpload.PostedFile` returns has an [`InputStream` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) you can read the uploaded file data from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this one http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246

```
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" +  fn;
try
{
    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
    Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
    //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
    //production environments. It would be better to put a generic error message. 
}
```